# CSS/Jquery Smooth Background Movement with Mouse

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get a smoothly panned zoomed image from mouse movement over a thumbnail.

I've tried all types of transition durations, custom tweening functions, jquery animate and none of it is getting a nice result.

When a thumbnail is small then the pixel jumps over it are large enough to make the image stagger.

Jquery animations start stacking, css transition changes abruptly, custom functions, no idea how to change direction easily.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Wonderfulx/pen/GRgRYBQ)

```js
const ZOOM_LEVEL = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thumb").mouseenter(enter);
  $(".thumb").mouseleave(leave);
  $('.thumb').mousemove(zoom);
});

function zoom(event) {
  const p = calculateZoomOverlay({x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY}, $(event.target));
  moveCursorOverlay(p.left, p.top);
  movePreviewBackground(p.offsetX, p.offsetY);
}

function calculateZoomOverlay(mouse, thumb) {
  let t = thumb.position();
  t.width = thumb.width();
  t.height = thumb.height();

  let z = {}; // Zoom overlay
  z.width = t.width / ZOOM_LEVEL;
  z.height = t.height / ZOOM_LEVEL;
  z.top = mouse.y - z.height / 2;
  z.left = mouse.x - z.width / 2;
  
  // Bounce off boundary
  if (z.top < t.top) z.top = t.top;
  if (z.left < t.left) z.left = t.left;
  if (z.top + z.height > t.top + t.height) z.top = t.top + t.height - z.height;
  if (z.left + z.width > t.left + t.width) z.left = t.left + t.width - z.width;

  z.offsetX = (z.left - t.left) / z.width * 100;
  z.offsetY = (z.top - t.top) / z.height * 100;

  return z;
}

function moveCursorOverlay(left, top) {
   $('.cursor-overlay').css({
    top: top,
    left: left
  });
}

function movePreviewBackground(offsetX, offsetY) {
  $('.preview').css({
    'background-position': offsetX + '% ' + offsetY + '%'
  });
}

function enter() {
  // Setup preview image
  const imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');
  const backgroundWidth = $('.preview').width() * ZOOM_LEVEL;
  $('.preview').css({
    'background-image': `url(${imageUrl})`,
    'background-size': `${backgroundWidth} auto`
  });
  $('.preview').show();

  $('.cursor-overlay').width($(this).width() / ZOOM_LEVEL);
  $('.cursor-overlay').height($(this).height() / ZOOM_LEVEL);
  $('.cursor-overlay').show();
}

function leave() {
  $('.preview').hide();
  $('.cursor-overlay').hide();
}
```

```css
.image-container {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.thumbnail-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.thumb {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
}

.thumb:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
}

.preview {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.cursor-overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 50, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/sbrYaxH.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/2PpkoRZ.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/3lOTtJV.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="cursor-overlay"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a case where in my opinion CSS transitions do not cut it. They are not generally great for interactive animations like this. Many animation libraries will also not get the job done.

To achieve this kind of interactive animation I like to use the following equation:

```
loc += (destination - location) / 2
```

This is an easing equation - great for interactive animation. It can be likened to [Zeno's Dichotomy paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)

Here we get the difference between a destination and a location on a single axis, we half that difference and add it to the current location.

When we apply this to your code we end up with:

```
 z.top += (dy - z.top) / SMOOTH;
 z.left += (dx - z.left) / SMOOTH;
```

For a more smooth animation we have a `SMOOTH` constant which I set to `8`. Have a look at how it ends up looking:

```js
const ZOOM_LEVEL = 2;
const SMOOTH = 8; // how much smoothness/delay do you want on the animation

let thumb = $('.thumb');
$(document).ready(function() {
  thumb.mouseenter(enter);
  thumb.mouseleave(leave);
  thumb.mousemove(move);
});

let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0; 
let z = { top: 0, left: 0 }; // Zoom overlay
let dx;
let dy;
function move(event) {
  mouseX = event.pageX;
  mouseY = event.pageY;
  thumb = $(event.target);
}

function loop() {
  const p = calculateZoomOverlay({x: mouseX, y: mouseY});
  moveCursorOverlay(p.left, p.top);
  movePreviewBackground(p.offsetX, p.offsetY);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

function calculateZoomOverlay(mouse) {
  let t = thumb.position();
  t.width = thumb.width();
  t.height = thumb.height();

  
  z.width = t.width / ZOOM_LEVEL;
  z.height = t.height / ZOOM_LEVEL;
  dy = mouse.y - z.height / 2;
  dx = mouse.x - z.width / 2;
  
  z.top += (dy - z.top) / SMOOTH;
  z.left += (dx - z.left) / SMOOTH;
  
  // Bounce off boundary
  if (z.top < t.top) z.top = t.top;
  if (z.left < t.left) z.left = t.left;
  if (z.top + z.height > t.top + t.height) z.top = t.top + t.height - z.height;
  if (z.left + z.width > t.left + t.width) z.left = t.left + t.width - z.width;

  z.offsetX = (z.left - t.left) / z.width * 100;
  z.offsetY = (z.top - t.top) / z.height * 100;

  return z;
}

function moveCursorOverlay(left, top) {
   $('.cursor-overlay').css({
    top: top,
    left: left
  });
}

function movePreviewBackground(offsetX, offsetY) {
  $('.preview').css({
    'background-position': offsetX + '% ' + offsetY + '%'
  });
}

function enter() {
  // Setup preview image
  const imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');
  const backgroundWidth = $('.preview').width() * ZOOM_LEVEL;
  $('.preview').css({
    'background-image': `url(${imageUrl})`,
    'background-size': `${backgroundWidth} auto`
  });
  $('.preview').show();

  $('.cursor-overlay').width($(this).width() / ZOOM_LEVEL);
  $('.cursor-overlay').height($(this).height() / ZOOM_LEVEL);
  $('.cursor-overlay').show();
}

function leave() {
  $('.preview').hide();
  $('.cursor-overlay').hide();
}
```

```css
.image-container {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.thumbnail-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.thumb {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
}

.thumb:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
}

.preview {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.cursor-overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 50, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/sbrYaxH.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/2PpkoRZ.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/3lOTtJV.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="cursor-overlay"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

You can adjust `SMOOTH` to your liking.

The structure of the code has changed slightly. Rather than performing the animation on mouse move... we now use a `requestAnimationFrame` to continuously calculate our animation and respond to changes of the variables `mouseX/Y`. This prevents abrupt stops in the animation when the user stops moving their mouse.

An optimization could be made to end the calculations if both the `z.top` and `z.left` values are very close to or equal to `dx` and `dy`. Probably not necessary unless you were dealing with many more calculations.

Comment: Smoothest answer. Slight lag moving around but I think it's good.

Comment: Did you try adjusting the `SMOOTH` value maybe to setting it to 2 or 4? Might help with the lag @JoshuaJenkins

Answer (score 4):

You could give transition property

```
<style>
.preview {
   display: none;
   margin-left: 15px;
   width: 640px;
   height: 400px;
   border: 3px solid orange;
   -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
   transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
</style>
```

```js
const ZOOM_LEVEL = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thumb").mouseenter(enter);
  $(".thumb").mouseleave(leave);
  $('.thumb').mousemove(zoom);
});

function zoom(event) {
  const p = calculateZoomOverlay({x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY}, $(event.target));
  moveCursorOverlay(p.left, p.top);
  movePreviewBackground(p.offsetX, p.offsetY);
}

function calculateZoomOverlay(mouse, thumb) {
  let t = thumb.position();
  t.width = thumb.width();
  t.height = thumb.height();

  let z = {}; // Zoom overlay
  z.width = t.width / ZOOM_LEVEL;
  z.height = t.height / ZOOM_LEVEL;
  z.top = mouse.y - z.height / 2;
  z.left = mouse.x - z.width / 2;
  
  // Bounce off boundary
  if (z.top < t.top) z.top = t.top;
  if (z.left < t.left) z.left = t.left;
  if (z.top + z.height > t.top + t.height) z.top = t.top + t.height - z.height;
  if (z.left + z.width > t.left + t.width) z.left = t.left + t.width - z.width;

  z.offsetX = (z.left - t.left) / z.width * 100;
  z.offsetY = (z.top - t.top) / z.height * 100;

  return z;
}

function moveCursorOverlay(left, top) {
   $('.cursor-overlay').css({
    top: top,
    left: left
  });
}

function movePreviewBackground(offsetX, offsetY) {
  $('.preview').css({
    'background-position': offsetX + '% ' + offsetY + '%'
  });
}

function enter() {
  // Setup preview image
  const imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');
  const backgroundWidth = $('.preview').width() * ZOOM_LEVEL;
  $('.preview').css({
    'background-image': `url(${imageUrl})`,
    'background-size': `${backgroundWidth} auto`
  });
  $('.preview').show();

  $('.cursor-overlay').width($(this).width() / ZOOM_LEVEL);
  $('.cursor-overlay').height($(this).height() / ZOOM_LEVEL);
  $('.cursor-overlay').show();
}

function leave() {
  $('.preview').hide();
  $('.cursor-overlay').hide();
}
```

```css
.image-container {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.thumbnail-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.thumb {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
}

.thumb:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px orange;
}

.preview {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.cursor-overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 50, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.preview {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  transition: background-position 0.1s ease-out;
}

.cursor-overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 50, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition-property: top, left;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/sbrYaxH.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/2PpkoRZ.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/3lOTtJV.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="cursor-overlay"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much smoother with animation frame in other answer. I tried transitions but not exactly smooth. At least on my slower laptop.

Answer (score 0):

```
.preview {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  transition: background-position 0.1s ease-out;
}

.cursor-overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 50, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition-property: top, left;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Doesn't look too bad. You can play around with transitions further.

Comment: Improvement but the other answer with animation frames a whole lot smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Some food for thought

```html
<img class="hover-zoom" src="https://i.imgur.com/RCX3U3B.png">
```

In you CSS:

```css
.hover-zoom {
   transition: 0.5s
}

.hover-zoom:hover {
   transform: scale(1.5)
}
```

On mouse hover on the image it will smoothly scale up from 1x to 1.5x size within 0.5 seconds. in the `hover` add any other settings you want to occur.

Comment: Originally I did this but I wanted to pan the zoomed image.